# how to show all of my component in the tab layout?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tabactivity

i am facing a problem and wish you help me..

i am using tabs in my code and and i added a lot of component in it (Buttons , ImageButtons, etc..) and i put this layout in the center of the screen and here is the problem because not all my component appear in my layout (some buttons appears and others not and i can't see
it or deal with it).

So can i shrink the component or customize it to appear fine?

iam using TableLayout to manage the component then i added this layout in the corresponding tab ..

can you help me in that?
thnaxx in advance.

Comment: Would scrolling the view solve your problem, or you're stuck to fit-the-screen-but-that's-it?

Comment: An image along with some code can help us better understanding and helping you for the problem you face!

Answer (score 0):

Give same weight to component in xml file .
i.e.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Hope it will solve the problem